# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I am inserting master and detail data using json function.
after inserting all data in the text box when I click save button then this
error show "500" and json return format is valid I already check json
format validation website. Now I am sharing json result you can see.

```
{"ItemCode":"001-0001","ItemDesc":"1","PackingDetail":"1","ReOrder_Lvl":"1","Curr_Qty":"1","Curr_Rate":"1","Curr_Value":"1","items":[{"Srno":"1","MUnitCode":"02","BasicUnit_Qty":"1","SaleRate":"1","TableName":"ItemMeasuring"},{"Srno":"1","God_ID":"2","Op_Qty":"1","Op_Amount":"1","TableName":"ItemOpening"}],"btnAddNew":"new"}
```

I am sharing everything means Controller code, HTML, javascript
function anyone tell me where I am wrong and what is the problem in my
code.

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Items_Insert(string ItemCode, string ItemDesc, string PackingDetail, int ReOrder_Lvl, float Curr_Qty, float Curr_Rate, float Curr_Value, Items[] items,  string btnAddNew)
        {
            string result = "Error! Order Is Not Complete!";
            try
            {
                objclsItems.mItems_Insert(ItemCode, ItemDesc, PackingDetail, ReOrder_Lvl, Curr_Qty, Curr_Value, Curr_Rate, items, btnAddNew);

                ViewBag.Message = "Your record has been inserted Successfully";
                ModelState.Clear();

                result = "Your record has been inserted Successfully!";

                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

 public int mItems_Insert(string ItemCode, string ItemDesc, string PackingDetail, int ReOrder_Lvl, float Curr_Qty, float Curr_Value, float Curr_Rate, Items[] items, string btnAddNew)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                tr = con.BeginTransaction();

                if (btnAddNew == "new")
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_ItemsInsert", con);
                else
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_ItemsUpdate", con);


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", ItemCode);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comp_Id", 1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemDesc", ItemDesc);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackingDetail", PackingDetail);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReOrder_Lvl", ReOrder_Lvl);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Curr_Qty", Curr_Qty);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Curr_Value", Curr_Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Curr_Rate", Curr_Rate);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                if (items != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (items[i].TableName == "ItemMeasuring")
                        {
                            if (btnAddNew == "new")
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_ItemMeasuringInsert", con);
                            else
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_ItemMeasuringUpdate", con);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", ItemCode);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comp_ID", 1);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MUnitCode", items[i].MUnitCode);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BasicUnit_Qty", items[i].BasicUnit_Qty);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SaleRate", items[i].SaleRate);

                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Transaction = tr;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        else if (items[i].TableName == "ItemOpening")
                        {
                            if (btnAddNew == "new")
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_ItemOpeningInsert", con);
                            else
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_ItemOpeningUpdate", con);

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", ItemCode);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comp_ID", 1);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GL_Year", "2018-2019");
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@God_ID", items[i].God_ID);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Op_Qty", items[i].Op_Qty);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Op_Amount", items[i].Op_Amount);

                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Transaction = tr;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }

                tr.Commit();
                return i;
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw sqlex;  // read all sql error 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw ex; // General execption

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Model:

```
public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public int Comp_Id { get; set; }
        public string ItemDesc { get; set; }

        public string PackingDetail { get; set; }
        public int ReOrder_Lvl { get; set; }
        public float Curr_Qty { get; set; }
        public float Curr_Value { get; set; }
        public float Curr_Rate { get; set; }

        public string MUnitCode { get; set; }
        public float BasicUnit_Qty { get; set; }
        public float SaleRate { get; set; }

        public float Op_Qty { get; set; }
        public float Op_Amount { get; set; }
        public int God_ID { get; set; }
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    //Show model
    function addNewOrder() {
        $("#ItemsNew").modal();
    }


    // Add Multiple Record (Item Measuring)

    $("#addToListitemmeasureing").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($.trim($("#MUnitCode").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#BasicUnit_Qty").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#SaleRate").val()) == "") return;


        var Srno = document.getElementById("detailsTableitemMeasuring").rows.length,
            MUnitCode = $("#MUnitCode").val(),
            BasicUnit_Qty = $("#BasicUnit_Qty").val(),
            SaleRate = $("#SaleRate").val(),
            detailsTableBodyMeasuring = $("#detailsTableitemMeasuring tbody");
        var ItemsMeasuring = '<tr><td>' + Srno + '</td><td>' + MUnitCode + '</td><td>' + BasicUnit_Qty + '</td><td>' + SaleRate + '</td><td> <a data - itemId="0" href= "#" class="deleteItem" > Remove</a ></td ></tr > ';
        detailsTableBodyMeasuring.append(ItemsMeasuring);
        clearItemMeasuring();
    });

    // Add Multiple Record (Item Opening)

    $("#addToListItemOpening").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($.trim($("#txtNGod_ID").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#Op_Qty").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#Op_Amount").val()) == "") return;


        var Srno = document.getElementById("detailsTableItemOpening").rows.length,
            God_ID = $("#txtNGod_ID").val(),
            Op_Qty = $("#Op_Qty").val(),
            Op_Amount = $("#Op_Amount").val(),
            detailsTableItemOpening = $("#detailsTableItemOpening tbody");
        var ItemsOpening = '<tr><td>' + Srno + '</td><td>' + God_ID + '</td><td>' + Op_Qty + '</td><td>' + Op_Amount + '</td><td> <a data-itemId="0" href = "#" class="deleteItem" > Remove</a ></td ></tr > ';
        detailsTableItemOpening.append(ItemsOpening);
        clearItemOpening();

    });

    //After Add A New Order In The List
    function clearItemMeasuring() {
        $("#MUnitCode").val('');
        $("#BasicUnit_Qty").val('');
        $("#SaleRate").val('');

    }

    function clearItemOpening() {
        $("#txtNGod_ID").val('');
        $("#Op_Qty").val('');
        $("#Op_Amount").val('');

    }

    // After Add A New Order In The List, If You Want, You Can Remove

    $(document).on('click', 'a.deleteItem', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $self = $(this);
        if ($(this).attr('data-itemId') == "0") {
            $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", "white").fadeOut(800, function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
    //After Click Save Button Pass All Data View To Controller For Save Database

    function saveItems(data) {

        return $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("Items_Insert")",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {

                JSON.parse(results);

                location.reload();
            },
            fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Could not get posts, server response: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            }

        }).responseJSON;

    }

    //Collect Multiple Order List For Pass To Controller (Item Measuring)

    $("#btnsaveItemS").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemMeasuringArr = [];
        itemMeasuringArr.length = 0;

        $.each($("#detailsTableitemMeasuring tbody tr"), function () {

            itemMeasuringArr.push({
                Srno: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                MUnitCode: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                BasicUnit_Qty: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(),
                SaleRate: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html(),
                TableName: 'ItemMeasuring'
            });
        });
            $.each($("#detailsTableItemOpening tbody tr"), function () {

                itemMeasuringArr.push({
                    Srno: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                    God_ID: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                    Op_Qty: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(),
                    Op_Amount: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html(),
                    TableName: 'ItemOpening'
                });
            });

            var data = JSON.stringify({
                ItemCode: $("#txtNItemCode").val(),
                ItemDesc: $("#txtNItemDesc").val(),
                PackingDetail: $("#txtNPackingDetail").val(),
                ReOrder_Lvl: $("#txtNReOrderLvl").val(),
                Curr_Qty: $("#txtNCurrQty").val(),
                Curr_Rate: $("#txtNCurrRate").val(),
                Curr_Value: $("#txtNValue").val(),
                items: itemMeasuringArr,

                btnAddNew: $("#btnAddNew").val()
            });

            //Collect Multiple Order List For Pass To Controller (Item Opening)

            $.when(saveItems(data)).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }).fail(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });


</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in show active" id="panel5" role="tabpanel">
                <br>
                <button type="button" id="btnAddNew" value="new" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ItemsNew" style="float:left">Add New Items</button>

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="jqGrid" class="table table-bordered table-striped"></table>
                    <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
                </div>

                <!--Add New Model Form-->

                <div class="modal fade" id="ItemsNew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-notify modal-info" role="document">
                        <!--Content-->

                        <div class="modal-content" style="width:140%">
                            <!--Header-->
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <p class="heading lead">Add New Items</p>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <!--Body-->
                            <form id="NewOrdersss">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="col" id="poidd">
                                            <!-- Purchase PO ID -->
                                            <label for="lblItemCode">Item Category</label>
                                            <div class="md-form">

                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CatCode, ViewBag.ItemCat as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-3", id = "txtNCCode", Required = true })

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <label for="lblItemCode">Item Code</label>
                                            <div class="md-form">

                                                @Html.TextBox("ItemCode", (String)ViewBag.ItemCodeMaxNo, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-3", @id = "txtNItemCode", Required = true, @Readonly=true })


                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col">

                                            <label for="lblPackingDetail"> Item Description</label>
                                            <div class="md-form">

                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ItemDesc, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtNItemDesc", Required = true })

                                            </div>
                                        </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                        <div class="col">

                                            <label for="lblPackingDetail"> Packing Detail</label>
                                            <div class="md-form">

                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PackingDetail, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtNPackingDetail", Required = true })

                                            </div>
                                        </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                        <div class="col">
                                            <label for="lblRe-OrderLevel"> Re-Order Level</label>
                                            <div class="md-form">

                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReOrder_Lvl, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtNReOrderLvl", Required = true })


                                            </div>
                                        </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;


                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="column d-inline-block">
                                            <h6 style="margin-top:10px;color:#ff6347">Stock on Hand</h6>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="col">

                                                    <div class="md-form">
                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Curr_Qty, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtNCurrQty", @placeholder = "" })
                                                        <label for="lblQuantity">Quantity</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <div class="col" style="margin-left:1.5%;">
                                                    <!-- SellerQuotRefNo -->
                                                    <div class="md-form">
                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Curr_Rate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtNCurrRate", @placeholder = "" })

                                                        <label for="lblNRate">Rate</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                                <div class="col" style="margin-left:1.5%;">
                                                    <!--SellerQuotDate -->
                                                    <div class="md-form">

                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Curr_Value, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtNValue", @placeholder = "" })

                                                        <label for="lblNValue"> Value</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <br />
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="column">

                                            <!--Detail-->
                                            <h5 style="margin-top:10px;color:#ff6347">Item Measuring</h5>


                                            <div class="form-row">

                                                <!-- Requisition Date -->
                                                <div class="col">

                                                    <label for="lbljob">Unit Description</label>
                                                    <div class="md-form">
                                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MUnitCode, ViewBag.munit as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "chosen-select", id = "MUnitCode", Required = true })

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <!-- Job -->
                                                    <div class="md-form">
                                                        <input type="number" id="BasicUnit_Qty" name="BasicUnit_Qty" placeholder="" class="form-control" />

                                                        <label for="lblQty">Qty</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <!-- Job -->
                                                    <div class="md-form">
                                                        <input type="number" id="SaleRate" name="SaleRate" placeholder="" class="form-control" />

                                                        <label for="lblSaleRate">Sale Rate</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-offset-2">
                                                    <a id="addToListitemmeasureing" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <table id="detailsTableitemMeasuring" class="table">
                                                <thead style="background-color:#007bff; color:white">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th style="width:2%">SrNo.</th>
                                                        <th style="width:40%">Unit Description</th>
                                                        <th style="width:15%">Qty</th>
                                                        <th style="width:30%">Sale Rate</th>
                                                        <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody></tbody>
                                            </table>




                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                        <!--Detail-->
                                        <h5 style="margin-top:10px;color:#ff6347">Item Opening</h5>
                                        <div class="form-row">

                                            <!-- Requisition Date -->
                                            <div class="col">

                                                <label for="lbljob">Warehouse Description</label>
                                                <div class="md-form">
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.God_ID, ViewBag.warehouse as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "chosen-select", id = "txtNGod_ID", Required = true })

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <!-- Job -->
                                                <div class="md-form">
                                                    <input type="number" id="Op_Qty" name="Op_Qty" placeholder="" class="form-control" />

                                                    <label for="lblOpeningQty">Opening Qty</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <!-- Job -->
                                                <div class="md-form">
                                                    <input type="number" id="Op_Amount" name="Op_Amount" placeholder="" class="form-control" />

                                                    <label for="lblOpeningAmount">Opening Amount</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-offset-2">
                                                <a id="addToListItemOpening" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <table id="detailsTableItemOpening" class="table">
                                            <thead style="background-color:#007bff; color:white">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th style="width:2%">SrNo.</th>
                                                    <th style="width:40%">Warehouse Description</th>
                                                    <th style="width:15%">Opening Qty</th>
                                                    <th style="width:30%">Opening Amount</th>

                                                    <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody></tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button id="btnsaveItemS" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>



                        </div>

                        <!--/.Content-->
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
```

Comment: That error means that an exception is occurring in your **server** code.

Comment: where i am sharing code can you tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: Your model is incorrect depending on the things you're sending to the server.
also change the `Comp_Id` to `String`

Comment: but I am not sent comp_id, I am hardcode comp_id not coming from json.

Comment: i also change com_id to string but the problem still same.

Comment: I also add the full function which I have to write in c# you can see.

Comment: problem in this arr   Items[] items which I am passing as a parameter when I remove this parameter json function call controller.

Comment: kindly tell me why json function not calling controller due to this arr what is the problem in this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **type** of all properties of JSON data have to corresponds the type of parameters of `Items_Insert` function to which you send the data. In your example, you send JSON data

```json
{
    "ItemCode": "001-0001",
    "ItemDesc": "1",
    "PackingDetail": "1",
    "ReOrder_Lvl": "1",
    "Curr_Qty": "1",
    "Curr_Rate": "1",
    "Curr_Value": "1",
    "items": [{
        "Srno": "1",
        "MUnitCode": "02",
        "BasicUnit_Qty": "1",
        "SaleRate": "1",
        "TableName": "ItemMeasuring"
    }, {
        "Srno": "1",
        "God_ID": "2",
        "Op_Qty": "1",
        "Op_Amount": "1",
        "TableName": "ItemOpening"
    }],
    "btnAddNew": "new"
}
```

where all properties are **strings**. On the other side you use

```
public ActionResult Items_Insert(string ItemCode, string ItemDesc, string PackingDetail,
     int ReOrder_Lvl, float Curr_Qty, float Curr_Rate, float Curr_Value,
     Items[] items,  string btnAddNew)
```

and some other properties of `Items`, which are not **strings** too:

```
public float BasicUnit_Qty { get; set; }
public float SaleRate { get; set; }
public float Op_Qty { get; set; }
public float Op_Amount { get; set; }
public int God_ID { get; set; }
```

Thus you have to send *another* formatted data to the server or to change the type of some parameters and properties from `int` of `float` to string.

I remind that JSON serialization of numbers are *not quoted* numbers like `1` instead of `"1"`.

To fix the problem on the client side you need to send the data like

```json
{
    "ItemCode": "001-0001",
    "ItemDesc": "1",
    "PackingDetail": "1",
    "ReOrder_Lvl": 1,
    "Curr_Qty": 1,
    "Curr_Rate": 1,
    "Curr_Value": 1,
    "items": [{
        "Srno": "1",
        "MUnitCode": "02",
        "BasicUnit_Qty": 1,
        "SaleRate": 1,
        "TableName": "ItemMeasuring"
    }, {
        "Srno": "1",
        "God_ID": 2,
        "Op_Qty": 1,
        "Op_Amount": 1,
        "TableName": "ItemOpening"
    }],
    "btnAddNew": "new"
}
```

Because of that you will need to add `parseInt` and `parseFloat` in some places of your JavaScript code. For example, you should use

```
...
God_ID: parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(), 10),
Op_Qty: parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(2)').html()),
...
```

instead of

```
...
God_ID: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
Op_Qty: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(),
...
```

used in your current code. You have to make close changes for **all** properties, which your interpret in your server code as float of integers instead of strings.

Comment: i have change in my code which you suggest me now json format is this :

Comment: {  
   "ItemCode":"001-0001",
   "ItemDesc":"sss",
   "PackingDetail":"asa",
   "ReOrder_Lvl":1,
   "Curr_Qty":1,
   "Curr_Rate":1,
   "Curr_Value":1,
   "items":[  
      {  
         "Srno":"1",
         "MUnitCode":5,
         "BasicUnit_Qty":1,
         "SaleRate":1,
         "TableName":"ItemMeasuring"
      },
      {  
         "Srno":"1",
         "God_ID":2,
         "Op_Qty":1,
         "Op_Amount":1,
         "TableName":"ItemOpening"
      }
   ],
   "btnAddNew":"new"
}

Comment: but problem is still same : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @journaltrend: It's better to fix the problem in steps. You can start with setting of breakpoint in the first line of your server code of `Items_Insert` and verifying that you get the data. If you don't get the data then you can reduce the number of parameters of `Items_Insert` to `public ActionResult Items_Insert(string ItemCode, string ItemDesc, string PackingDetail)` then to `public ActionResult Items_Insert(string ItemCode, string ItemDesc, string PackingDetail, int ReOrder_Lvl)` and so on. Every time you should just verify that the breakpoint of first line will be archived only.

Comment: I already do this problem in item[] item parameter,  when I remove then controller called other not response.

Comment: @journaltrend: You can try to replace *Items[]* to *List<Items>* or to reduce the number of properties in *Items* to verify which property is the origin of your problem. You don't posted the exact class definition of *Items* and just wrote about some "Model". You declare the parameter as `Items[]`. Thus the definition of public class *Items* inclusive all properties will be important to know. Sometimes one need to make some properties nullable to make all working.